# How do I divide a block of text into individual sentences in SQL server?

Tags: sql-server, parsing, text

I have a block of text with multiple sentences and I want to split them up and show each sentence on a new line. I have tried using CHARINDEX and SUBSTRING but once you get passed the second sentence the code becomes very complex and difficult to repeat. Here I got to two and gave up realising that the code was going to snowball rapidly :

```
DECLARE @TEXT NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'Has many applications. The price is low. The quality is good. Availability is widespread.'
DECLARE @TEXTLine1 NVARCHAR(MAX) = LEFT(@TEXT,CHARINDEX('.',@TEXT))
DECLARE @TEXTLine2 NVARCHAR(MAX) = SUBSTRING(@TEXT,CHARINDEX('.',@TEXT)+2,CHARINDEX('.',SUBSTRING(@TEXT,CHARINDEX('.',@TEXT)+2,50)))
PRINT @TEXTLine1
PRINT @TEXTLine2
```

As you can see, I am splitting the sentences based on the full stop. Is there a way to tell SUBSTRING to find the 'nth' instance of a character? This would make the task simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of a parsing function

```
Declare @TEXT VarChar(max) = 'Price if $15.25 is NOT split. Has many applications. The price is low. The quality is good. Availability is widespread.'

Select * from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse](@Text,'. ')
```

Returns

```
Key_PS  Key_Value
1       Price if $15.25 is NOT split
2       Has many applications
3       The price is low
4       The quality is good
5       Availability is widespread.
```

The UDF

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse] (@String varchar(max),@delimeter varchar(10))
--Usage: Select * from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse]('Dog,Cat,House,Car',',')
--       Select * from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse]('John Cappelletti was here',' ')
--       Select * from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse]('id26,id46|id658,id967','|')

Returns @ReturnTable Table (Key_PS int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL , Key_Value varchar(max))

As

Begin
   Declare @intPos int,@SubStr varchar(max)
   Set @IntPos = CharIndex(@delimeter, @String)
   Set @String = Replace(@String,@delimeter+@delimeter,@delimeter)
   While @IntPos > 0
      Begin
         Set @SubStr = Substring(@String, 0, @IntPos)
         Insert into @ReturnTable (Key_Value) values (@SubStr)
         Set @String = Replace(@String, @SubStr + @delimeter, '')
         Set @IntPos = CharIndex(@delimeter, @String)
      End
   Insert into @ReturnTable (Key_Value) values (@String)
   Return 
End
```

Comment: Perfect! I hadn't thought about decimal places. All I had to add was: IIF(right(Key_value,1)= '.',Key_value, Key_value+'.') to make sure all lines came back with a full stop at the end.

Comment: Happy to help.  I've been bit by that dog in the past. Cheers.

Comment: Been playing around with this today - what does the line 'Set @String = Replace(@String,@delimeter+@delimeter,@delimeter)' do?

Comment: @SteelyDanFan Eliminates double delimiters which would generate an empty row.

Comment: @SteelyDanFan For the record, there are countless parsing functions in the wild.   This one works for me, and it is tried and true.   It even benchmarks better than many of the XML methods

Comment: Got it. The function does indeed work very well - thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

use one of the split string functions from [here](http://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings)..

Then that would be very easy to do like this..

```
DECLARE @TEXT NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'Has many applications. The price is low. The quality is good. Availability is widespread.'

select * from
[dbo].[SplitStrings_Numbers](@text,'.')
```

**Output:**

```
Item
 Has many applications
 The price is low
 The quality is good
 Availability is widespread
```

Answer (score 0):

While considering my question I came up with this - it seems a bit overkill but I can't think of any other way:

```
DECLARE @text NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'Has many applications. The price is low. The quality is good. Availability is widespread.'; --Set text.
DECLARE @text2 NVARCHAR(MAX) = LEFT(@text,CHARINDEX('.',@text)); --Extract first sentence.

PRINT @text2; --Print first sentence.

SET @text = RIGHT(@text,LEN(@text)-LEN(@text2)); --Subtract @text2 from @text - will include the space at the begining that was after the first full stop.

WHILE LEN(@text) >0 
BEGIN 
SET @text = RIGHT(@text, LEN(@text)-1);--Take of the space that after the full stop in previous iteration of @text.
SET @text2 = LEFT(@text,CHARINDEX('.',@text));--Exract the 'new' first sentence.
PRINT @text2; 
SET @text = RIGHT(@text,LEN(@text)-LEN(@text2)); --Subtract @text2 from @text - will include the space at the begining that was after the first full stop.
END;
```

Other suggestions are welcome.

EDIT - John Cappelletti's excellent answer motivated me to improve my own. It now doesn't get caught out by decimals and can also recognise carriage returns. Will have a diffrent application but thought it might be useful to include for anyone looking for either solution.

```
DECLARE @text NVARCHAR(MAX) = 
'I would like to pay £22.99. Has many applications. 
£45.00 is good value. The price is low. The quality is good. 
Availability is widespread. Good value at £5.00.' --Set text.
DECLARE @text2 NVARCHAR(MAX) = LEFT(@text,CHARINDEX('. ',@text)) --Extract first sentence.


PRINT @text2 --Print first sentence.
SET @text = RIGHT(@text,LEN(@text)-LEN(@text2)) --Subtract @text2 from @text - will include the space at the begining that was after the first full stop.
WHILE LEN(@text) >0 
BEGIN 
SET @text = RIGHT(@text, LEN(@text)-1)--Take off the space that after the full stop in previous iteration of @text.
SET @text2 = IIF(LEN(LEFT(@text,CHARINDEX('. ',@text)))=0, LEFT(@text,CHARINDEX('.',@text)+LEN(RIGHT(@text, LEN(@text)-LEN(LEFT(@text,CHARINDEX('.',@text)))))),LEFT(@text,CHARINDEX('. ',@text)))--Extract the new first sentence.
PRINT @text2 
SET @text = RIGHT(@text,LEN(@text)-LEN(@text2)) --Subtract @text2 from @text - will include the space at the begining that was after the first full stop.
END
```